# How do I evaluate $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^2\sin(xy^2)}{x^4+9y^4}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I have tried multiple paths to see if they have differing limits, but they all lead to 0, so I'm assuming that is the limit. Then, I tried using Squeeze Theorem, but it doesn't seem to work. This is my current progress:
$$x^4+9y^4\geq x^4$$
$$\frac{x^2}{x^4+9y^4}\leq\frac{1}{x^2}$$
$$0\leq\left|\frac{x^2\sin(xy^2)}{x^4+9y^4}\right|\leq\left|\frac{\sin(x^2y)}{x^2}\right|$$
and I'm stuck in evaluating the limit of the upper bound.

Comment: Hint: $|\sin t| \le |t|$ for each $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Using this I got the upper bound $\left|\frac{x^3y^2}{x^4+9y^4}\right|$, but how do I evaluate it's limit?

Comment: Use AM-GM inequality on the denominator: $x^4+9y^4 \geq 6x^2y^2$

Comment: @Kaf Use that in $\left|\frac{\sin(x^2 y)}{x^2}\right|$.

Comment: @Bernkastel Ok I got it now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

just assume that
$$u = x^2y$$
So,
$$x^2=\frac{u}{y}$$
so the upper bound becomes:
$$\frac{sin(u)y}{u}$$
and that approaches zero

or just multibly and divide by y